# Erase iOS device with recovery mode without updating to latest iOS version?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud, recovery

I have an iPad 3 (A1430, on iOS 9.0.2) that I lost the passcode for. I know the iCloud/Apple ID account that iPad has and I can see an iCloud backup of it online (on the iCloud website). I tried following the recommended recovery options for a lost passcode but it seems my computer was never used to backup this iPad. Find My iPhone also doesn't work because the iPad doesn't seem to be connected to the WiFi network.

From instructions, my option is to use Recovery Mode to reset everything.

My problem is that it seems it will also update to the latest iOS version which I don't want do to.

Is there any way to unlock this device or do the recovery mode reset without updating the iOS version?

Comment: Which iPad model? And why don’t you want to update?

Comment: @Harcker thanks, updated to tell the model. Don't want to update because it 'just works' and updating can always bring slowdowns. (also jailbreak is easier on my current version)

Comment: The answer is no. You can’t do this. Apple specifically built their system so you can’t restore to old iOS versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to download the IPSW file and hold down Option key on your Mac (for Windows its <kbd>Alt</kbd>) on restore to open the link to restore from downloaded IPSW file.

I know it can be done with update but I'm not sure it can with restore.

You can get the IPSW file for your iPad on [IPSW Homepage](https://ipsw.me).

Comment: This won’t work anymore, restore’s won’t go theough unless the iOS version is being signed by Apple.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy agreed, but at the time it worked